# using mutexes and condition_variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-interprocess

I'm looking for correct pattern of the interconnectivity between two threads using boost interprocess library. I don't think there is a something specific for the library unlike of typical parallel programming using standard library. 
So I'm looking for a basic technique and understanding of these sync primitives usage.

There are two threads: writer and reader , which are using a shared memory. Named mutex used for a sync an access to objects (string and vector) in shared memory. conditional variable used for a waiting when readerwill have written a data into shared memory. So the scenario is :
 - reader starts and init conditional variable on named mutex with condition that vector with data should be non-empty. and waits...
 - writer locks the mutex and fills up the vector 
 - writer "notifies one" that writing to data vector has been finished and unlocks the mutex
 - reader receives a notification , locks the mutex and processes data in a vector.

after that,  reader should notify a writer that a reading was finished and vector can be fill up again with a new portion of the data.

so I'm not sure how to set all these waits and notifies correctly. Looks like my version does a deadlock. Please advise.

reader's thread code

```
    namespace bi = boost::interprocess;
    using bi_char_vector = bi::vector<char, CharAllocator>;

    bi::named_mutex             mtx{bi::open_or_create, "mtx"};
    bi::named_condition         cnd{bi::open_or_create, "cnd"};

    data = segment.find_or_construct<bi_char_vector>("data")(segment.get_segment_manager());
    while (!done) {
       bi::scoped_lock<bi::named_mutex> lock{mtx};
       cnd.wait(lock, [data] {return !data->empty(); });

       // process the data...

       cnd.notify_one();
    }
```

writer's thread code:

```
    bi::managed_shared_memory segment(bi::open_only, shm_name.c_str());
    bi::named_mutex mtx{bi::open_only, "mtx"};
    bi::named_condition cnd(bi::open_only, "cnd");

    data = segment.find_or_construct<bi_char_vector>("data")(segment.get_segment_manager());

    for(std::size_t chunk_num = 0; chunk_num < chunk_count; ++chunk_num) {
        bi::scoped_lock<bi::named_mutex> lock { mtx };
        cnd.wait(lock);
        data->clear();
        // fills the data
        cnd.notify_one();
    }
}
```

if I'm setting the wait in writer loop, it stops on this,
if I'm removing this wait, looks like reader receives and processes last loop iteration only

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.
on reader's side added:

```
while (!done) {
   bi::scoped_lock<bi::named_mutex> lock{mtx};
   cnd.wait(lock, [data] {return !data->empty(); });

   // process the data...

   data->clear();
   cnd.notify_one();
}
```

on writer side:

```
    for(std::size_t chunk_num = 0; chunk_num < chunk_count; ++chunk_num) {
        bi::scoped_lock<bi::named_mutex> lock { mtx };
        cnd.wait(lock, [data] {return data->empty(); });
        //...
        cnd.notify_one();
    }
```

and now it works as expected